# Regular Expression To Find Word Document Text of Similar Format, but Varying Length

Tags: c#, regex, ms-word

Given a sample of some possible text containing the format

```
$[I-VI].[1-99].[1-99].[1-99]…
```

I am trying to build a regular expression that will find all text formatted this way.

So, some samples might be

- $II.4.13
- $V.23.38.1.23
- $IV.1.1.1.1.1

As you can see, the length of the text is varying, but there are some known parameters. The most levels deep is 7, the $ always exists and there is always a . separating all roman numerals / numbers (except the last number).

Any suggestions? Admittedly, I am currently weak in determining regular expressions.

I am using Word 2010 to try to find this text in a document, so Microsoft Office RegEx syntax would be preferred; but C# would be fine too as I could write a program to search the text and find this text as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\$(I|II|III|IV|V|VI)(\.[0-9]{1,2})+`

Comment: Thanks. I am assuming this is a C# version of the required regular expression?

Comment: Yes. It could be somewhat improved because [0-9]{1,2} matches also things like 01 or 00 but that would complicate it and probably to no good purpose